# Checkout: is there a shop search input field by default?

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

Problem:

On checkout page there is a "Sign In" link that overlays mini-cart-icon/search ...

[image]

I have no completly fresh installation, but i doubt it come from any extension. (they do not effect checkout or header)

I just quickly checked checkout in some M2 demo stores and noticed two things ...

- there is no search or mini-cart on other pages
- there is not even a top bar on other pages

Is it possibly a config setting or its maybe related to multistore-setup?

Tested with 2.2.5 and updated to 2.2.6 ...

Any ideas (before i test it on clean install :P)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOt Available of **Search box and menu, mini cart  at Checkout page** is Magento 2 default feature and depend on page layout. There are **not related** to config setting or multistore-setup.

Magento2 create a specific layout for checkout page `layout="checkout"` .

See at [`checkout_index_index.xml`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml#L8)

`<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">`

And that layout **checkout** has been defined at  [Magento_Checkout](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml#L8)

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="empty"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="checkout.header.container" as="checkout_header_container" label="Checkout Page Header Container" htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content">
            <container name="checkout.header.wrapper" label="Checkout Page Header" as="checkout_header_wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="logo" destination="checkout.header.wrapper"/>
```

*If any demo store using the `checkout`layout thenn that demo site  checkout does not have  any Search box and menu, mini cart .*

Comment: If its default behavoir, that search and mini-cart is not displayed, why is it display in my store? (or did I misunderstood you?)

Comment: It is depeds on layout.Please check your checkout page layout

Comment: Thanks Amit. Installed to other stores and its OK there.